# Python script acts differently when ran in console and when ran from other file

Tags: python, pandas

I have two python files, when I run "python downloader.py todownload" it downloads images from todownload.txt file, but when I run it indirectly (calling function of downloader.py via other python file) I don't get the images downloaded.

I tried debugging and printing what arguments are sent to function "download_all_images(args)" when I call it both ways, and the object args match.

**downloader.py**

```
import argparse
from concurrent import futures
import os
import re
import sys

import boto3
import botocore
import tqdm

BUCKET_NAME = 'open-images-dataset'
REGEX = r'(test|train|validation|challenge2018)/([a-fA-F0-9]*)'


def check_and_homogenize_one_image(image):
  split, image_id = re.match(REGEX, image).groups()
  yield split, image_id


def check_and_homogenize_image_list(image_list):
  for line_number, image in enumerate(image_list):
    try:
      yield from check_and_homogenize_one_image(image)
    except (ValueError, AttributeError):
      raise ValueError(
          f'ERROR in line {line_number} of the image list. The following image '
          f'string is not recognized: "{image}".')


def read_image_list_file(image_list_file):
  with open(image_list_file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
      yield line.strip().replace('.jpg', '')


def download_one_image(bucket, split, image_id, download_folder):
  try:
    bucket.download_file(f'{split}/{image_id}.jpg',
                         os.path.join(download_folder, f'{image_id}.jpg'))
  except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as exception:
    sys.exit(
        f'ERROR when downloading image `{split}/{image_id}`: {str(exception)}')


def download_all_images(args):
  print(type(args))
  print(args)
  """Downloads all images specified in the input file."""
  bucket = boto3.resource(
      's3', config=botocore.config.Config(
          signature_version=botocore.UNSIGNED)).Bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

  download_folder = args['download_folder'] or os.getcwd()

  if not os.path.exists(download_folder):
    os.makedirs(download_folder)

  try:
    image_list = list(
        check_and_homogenize_image_list(
            read_image_list_file(args['image_list'])))
  except ValueError as exception:
    sys.exit(exception)

  progress_bar = tqdm.tqdm(
      total=len(image_list), desc='Downloading images', leave=True)
  with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(
      max_workers=args['num_processes']) as executor:
    all_futures = [
        executor.submit(download_one_image, bucket, split, image_id,
                        download_folder) for (split, image_id) in image_list
    ]
    for future in futures.as_completed(all_futures):
      future.result()
      progress_bar.update(1)
  progress_bar.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
      description=__doc__, formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
  parser.add_argument(
      'image_list',
      type=str,
      default=None,
      help=('Filename that contains the split + image IDs of the images to '
            'download. Check the document'))
  parser.add_argument(
      '--num_processes',
      type=int,
      default=5,
      help='Number of parallel processes to use (default is 5).')
  parser.add_argument(
      '--download_folder',
      type=str,
      default=None,
      help='Folder where to download the images.')
  download_all_images(vars(parser.parse_args()))
```

**imagegatherer.py**

```
import pandas as pd
import argparse
from concurrent import futures
import os
import re
import sys

import boto3
import botocore
import tqdm

import downloader

labels = pd.read_csv('class-descriptions-boxable.csv', header=None)
labels.columns = ['id', 'name']


classified = pd.read_csv('train-annotations-human-imagelabels-boxable.csv', nrows=2500)

classes = ['Apple', 'Motorcycle', 'Snowman']
ids = labels[labels['name'].isin(classes)]



for entry in ids.iterrows():
    id = entry[1][0]
    name = entry[1][1]

    good = classified.loc[classified['LabelName'] == id]['ImageID'].tolist()


    with open('todownload.txt', 'w') as file:
        for img in good:
            file.write('train/' + img + '\n')

        args = dict()
        args['image_list'] = 'todownload.txt'
        args['num_processes'] = 5
        args['download_folder'] = None
        

        downloader.download_all_images(args)
```

todownload.txt content that should download 4 images:
train/0000048549557964
train/000023aa04ab09ed
train/00002f4ff380c64c
train/000037c2dd414b46

Comment: are the 3 of the files in the same folder?

Comment: Yes, downloader.py imagegatherer.py and  todownload.txt ar in same folder